# Extracting values from HTML to json file

Tags: javascript, python, html, json

I'm trying to extract values from elements in multiple HTML files.

My folder structure looks something like this:

```
|root
    |1
        |post
            |post.html
    |2
        |post
            |post.html
    |3
        |post
            |post.html
...
```

I want to run a script that reads the HTML files and outputs a JSON file in the same folder with values of desired fields.

```
|root
    |1
        |post
            |post.html
            |post.json
    |2
        |post
            |post.html
            |post.json
    |3
        |post
            |post.html
            |post.json
...
```

If I open the HTML files in chrome, and in dev tools, I can use a simple function along the lines of:

```
const getPostData = () => {
    let res = {};
    var a = document.getElementsByName('post_title')[0]?.value;
    res['post_title'] = a;
... ...
    return res;
}
```

The returned value is what I want saved to the json file. However, I'm not sure how to get the document variable I need from the HTML files without manually opening them in a browser.

I'm quite new to web development, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: two options if need python to automate this. 1st. Selenium to open the files, select the element's text, build the json and save the file. 2nd. Beautiful soup to build a soup and then extract the data, build the json and save the json file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use beautifulsoup4 & json for that.If i am right, you want something like that

```
from os import path 
import json 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
 
def get_post_data(soup):
    post_title = soup.find_all(attrs={"name": "post_title"})
    if post_title:
       return {'post_title':post_title[0].text}

def main():
  filepaths = [path.join(curr_folder,"post") for curr_folder in os.listdir()]

  for html_filepath in filepaths:
      soup = bs(html_filepath , 'html.parser')
      data = get_post_data(soup)
      if data:
         json_filepath = html_filepath.split('.')[0] + '.json'
         with open(json_filepath,"w") as out_file:
             json.dump(data,out_file)
```